# How to combine flatmap so it only needs to be used once

Tags: swift

I have a class which I need to find the minimum/maximum value for different variables in the data set. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
guard let maxValPerc = data.flatMap({$0.percent}).max() else {return}
guard let minValProf = data.flatMap({$0.profitLoss}).min() else {return}
guard let minValPrice = data.flatMap({$0.price}) else {return}
guard let minValOther = data.flatMap({$0.other}).min() else {return}
guard let minVal = data.flatMap({$0.value}).min() else {return}
```

The problem with this is that it is running the loop through all my data each time I use flatmap. What is a better way to do this? It is all with the same dataset called `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear what your data type is, but I'm assuming it's something like this (since you're using `flatMap`):

```
struct Value {
    let percent: Int?
    let profitLoss: Int?
    let price: Int?
    let other: Int?
    let value: Int?
}
```

You're trying to go from a list, to a single (tuple) value:

```
var result: (maxPercent: Int?, minProfitLoss: Int?, minPrice: Int?, minOther: Int?, minValue: Int?)
```

That suggests `reduce`. But you'll need a way to combine `Int?` using `max` in some cases and `min` in other cases. That suggests a function like this:

```
func combine(_ x: inout Int?, with: Int?, using: (Int, Int) -> Int) {
    guard let x_ = x else { x = with; return }
    guard let with = with else { return }
    x = using(x_, with)
}
```

And then put it together with `reduce`:

```
data.reduce(into: result) { (acc, value) in
    combine(&acc.maxPercent, with: value.percent, using: max)
    combine(&acc.minProfitLoss, with: value.profitLoss, using: min)
    combine(&acc.minPrice, with: value.price, using: min)
    combine(&acc.minOther, with: value.other, using: min)
    combine(&acc.minValue, with: value.value, using: min)
}
```

And unload the tuple for your `guard` if you like.

```
guard let maxPercent = result.maxPercent,
    let minProfitLoss = result.minProfitLoss,
    let minPrice = result.minPrice,
    let minOther = result.minOther,
    let minValue = result.minValue
    else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change you code this the follow snippet

```
func separeteDate() {

var percents        : [Int] = []
var profitLosses    : [Int] = []
var prices          : [Int] = []
var others          : [Int] = []
var values          : [Int] = []

for singleData in data {
    if let percent = singleData.percent {
        percents.append(percent)
    }

    if let price = singleData.price {
        prices.append(price)
    }

    if let other = singleData.other {
        others.append(other)
    }

    if let value = singleData.value {
        values.append(value)
    }

    if let profitLoss = singleData.profitLoss {
        profitLosses.append(profitLoss)
    }
}

  guard let maxValPerc = percents.max() else { return }
  guard let minValProf = profitLosses.min() else { return }
  guard let minValPrice = prices.min() else { return }
  guard let minValOther = others.max() else { return }
  guard let minVal = values.min() else { return }

}
```

You will need more codes, but less loops. For this example I considerate your struct just have Int values.

Comment: Note that OP is using flatMap probably because all properties from his class are optionals (Double)

Comment: Or probably because it can be an array of array. flatMap is not used just because have optionals. But what you said makes total sense.

Comment: Note that the max/min method would also iterate all elements of each array